# mingw64 linkder(ld) error: XXX.a: lib file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: c++, cygwin, mingw, ld

I build C++ application with mingw64 in Cygwin.
If I don't compile the project in a few hours, then I ran into the error that it complains the existing xxx.a lib file not recognized when one CPP file is modified. I have to call make clean and rebuild everything. It's too time-consuming.
What could cause this trouble?

Comment: lib files don't magically become corrupt. Is something modifying it behind your back? Do the creation and modification times match?

Comment: a virus maybe. or an antivirus. they are nearly indistinguishable these days.

Comment: The .a file may have multiple object files in it. But your makefile may delete xxx.a when any object file is updated. For sure it sounds like `make clean` does delete xxx.a. Instead, you may need to replace the old object file in the xxx.a with the new one. See doc for the ar command. Try `ar tv xxx.a`.

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual error message.